# How to determine which variables are the most important to define each cluster from a Hierarchical clustering analysis, using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

After searching, reading posts, and trying to solve this issue myself for several days, I think it's time to ask for help.

I'm performing a Hierarchical Clustering analysis on a dataset, that includes hundreds of samples and thousands of variables. Once I got the optimal number of clusters, graphical representations, and a table with the sample/cluster relations, it is time to figure out which variables are the most important to define each cluster. I'm looking for a method to obtain a table where each of the variables is assigned to the cluster it contributes the most (eg. Variable X/ Cluster N)

Do you know of any R package or any piece of code that would allow me to do this? At the moment, I have used the following R packages for the rest of the analysis (cluster, factoextra, NbClust, caret, and dendextend), but, I have been unable to figure out any way of using them to achieve this final aim.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

JL

Comment: Welcome to CV. You wrote

> Once I got the optimal number of clusters, graphical representations,
> and a table with the sample/cluster relations, it is time to figure
> out which variables are the most important to define each cluster.

Why is it time to do this?  What do you want to gain? Are you considering not collecting all the variables for some future data set? Or what?

Comment: Also, in order to answer this question, you will have to say what you mean by "most important".  This isn't easy. One method might be to rerun the clustering, leaving out one variable at a time, and using some metric to measure how different the results are.